# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - ASP.NET application missing images

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net, elastic-beanstalk

Whenever I deploy my ASP.NET application to EBS it is missing most of the images, as if they are not getting uploaded. I suspect I need to configure something correctly, but I can't see what. In my Properties window Package/Publish Web tab I checked Items to Deploy: All Files in this Project. But it didn't do the trick.
Please help.